# Extra certs issue with Nginx SSL config

Tags: nginx, ssl, certificate, linode

It seems that I've set up my SSL wrong. SSL labs gives me the following:

https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=pitot.io&hideResults=on

The issue in question is "extra certs". This doesn't seem to be a big issue for most browsers, but chrome on android really really doesn't like it and shows up a large warning page.

I followed the following tutorial:

https://gentlenode.com/journal/nginx-1-set-up-gandi-standard-ssl-certificate/2

Comment: That tutorial web site is broken. Please explain exactly _what you did_ to set up your SSL.

Comment: Sorry, you can get to the results by putting "pitot.io" into https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/index.html

I followed the instructions on the gentlenode website to a T. I am with gandi and I use nginx.

Comment: I can see your ssllabs results just fine. As I already said, it's the _other_ web site that doesn't work.

Comment: I'm a bit confused, it is working for me in safari, chrome and firefox.

Comment: Please just provide the requested information, so that your question is complete. Even if the site worked, it would be inappropriate to omit it.

Comment: Generated a keypair with "sudo openssl genrsa -des3 -out gentlenode.com_encrypted.key 4096", then a CSR with "sudo openssl req -new -key gentlenode.com_encrypted.key -out gentlenode.com.csr"

Downloaded the gandi cert and concatenated it: sudo cat GandiStandardSSLCA.pem >> gentlenode.com.crt

In nginx site config:

ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/gentlenode.com.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/gentlenode.com.key;

Comment: Add the information to the question with proper formatting, it is not readable in a comment.

Comment: You are missing the 'USERTrust RSA CA'. You should get that one by your CA which signed your CSR.